# Apps Script run onEdit on specific tab/sheet only

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sure there is a very simple answer to this question;

I have a function that works perfectly, however it only works if the function name is 'onEdit' which is not what i want as i want to create similar functions for different tabs, hence the first line checking the sheet name, can someone please point out the error of my ways :-) thanks.

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "PrintNoteLines") {  
  return}
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
    if (sh.getName().indexOf('PrintNoteLines') > -1 && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B1' && e.value) {
        sh.getRange('A25:A183')
                .setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                .requireValueInRange(e.source.getRangeByName(e.value), true)
                .setAllowInvalid(false)
                .build());                                                                         }
                        }
```

Answer (score 3):

- `onEdit` is a key word defining that the function is bound to a simple [`onEdit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- If you want to rename the function, but maintain the functionality, you can use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onEdit` trigger instead
- See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) how to bind it to your renamed function
- Mind that having more than one function runing on `onEdit` can lead to conflicts and it mostly not necessary
- You can call other functions from inside the `onEdit` triggerred funciton if necessary

Sample:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "A") {  
  function1();
  }
else if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "B") {  
  function2();
  }
else {  
  function3();
  }
}
function function1(){
 Logger.log("The sheet name is A");
}
function function2(){
 Logger.log("The sheet name is B");
}
function function3(){
 Logger.log("The sheet name is different");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have two options:**

- You can either create additional if conditions to your existing `onEdit(e)` function to execute different
  code when different sheets are edited.
- You can create a main `onEdit(e)` trigger function that feeds all the other `functionName(e)`.

**For example:**

Rename the function of your current code to `myFunction1(e)`:

```
function myFunction1(e) {
if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "PrintNoteLines") {  
  return}
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
    if (sh.getName().indexOf('PrintNoteLines') > -1 && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B1' && e.value) {
        sh.getRange('A25:A183')
                .setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                .requireValueInRange(e.source.getRangeByName(e.value), true)
                .setAllowInvalid(false)
                .build());                                                                         }
                        }
```

and then feed the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) from the `onEdit(e)` function like that:

```
function onEdit(e){
myFunction1(e) 
}
```

In this way you can have **multiple** functions being executed after an edit is made:

```
function onEdit(e){
myFunction1(e);
myFunction2(e);
myFunction3(e)
...

}
```